# How to make embeded Account Kit form?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, account-kit

I want to make use of Facebook's Account Kit on my web app. Is there any chance to get embedded form like on [its official page](https://accountkit.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not embedded, but there is now a new feature where it will show in a modal dialog with the parameter: display=modal. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs/reference for reference